# create a regular expression to "nam12 = 34.24" boost

Tags: c++, boost

please help create a regular expression to "nam12 = 34.24"

```
boost::regex regex();
boost::cmatch result;
std::string identifier;
std::string value;
if (boost::regex_match(assign.c_str(), result, regex))
{
    identifier = std::string(result[1].first, result[1].second);
    value = std::string(result[2].first, result[2].second);
}
```

Comment: So - what regex have you tried?

Comment: What do you want the result of this code to be? If it's as simple as it superficially appears to be, a regular expression is overkill.

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree std::istream would be enough for this, but regex actually does too little for me (no typed extraction/validation).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about he overkill, but I like to use Spirit for simple tasks like this:

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

int main() {
    std::string input;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, input)) 
    {
        std::string name;
        double value;

        using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
        if (phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), lexeme[+alnum] >> '=' >> double_, space, name, value))
            std::cout << "Parsed: name = '" << name << "' and value = " << value << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints e.g.

```
Parsed: name = 'nam12' and value = 34.24
Parsed: name = 'nam56' and value = 43.65
```

See it [Live On Wandbox](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/CBRT1nDBYNglhDL4)